# How to using lapply on str_replace_all and hunspell_suggest to replace all misspelled words?

Tags: r, stringr, hunspell

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate `str_replace_all` and `hunspell_suggest` together in an lapply. Here is my current situation:

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
library(hunspell)
df1 <- data.frame("Index" = 1:7, "Text" = c("Brad came to dinner with us tonigh.",
                                            "Wuld you like to trave with me?",
                                            "There is so muh to undestand.",
                                            "Sentences cone in many shaes and sizes.",
                                            "Learnin R is fun",
                                            "yesterday was Friday",
                                            "bing search engine"))
```

Here are my codes to identify words that are mispelled in the column:

```
df1$Text <- as.character(df1$Text)
df1$word_check <- hunspell(df1$Text)
```

However, I'm stuck when it comes to replacing the misspelled words using the first suggestions from `hunspell_suggest`

I tried this following code but it can only do 1 row and only with rows that has 1 misspelled word such that:

```
df1$replace <- str_replace_all(df1$Text, df1$word_check[[1]], hunspell_suggest(df1$word_check[[1]])[[1]][1])
```

I'm not sure on how to incorporate `lapply` onto the code above to effectively replace all misspelled words with the first suggestion based on `hunspell_suggest` and leave those correct words alone.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one solution using the `DataCombine` package:

```
library(DataCombine)

# vector of words to replace
wrong <- unlist(hunspell(df1$Text))
# vector of the first suggested words
correct <- sapply(wrong, function(x) hunspell_suggest(x)[[1]][1])

Replaces <- data.frame(from = wrong, to = correct)

FindReplace(data = df1, Var = "Text", replaceData = Replaces,
                       from = "from", to = "to", exact = FALSE)

#Index                                   Text
#1     1   Brad came to dinner with us tonight.
#2     2        Wald you like to trace with me?
#3     3         There is so hum to understand.
#4     4 Sentences cone in many shes and sizes.
#5     5                      Learning R is fun
#6     6                   yesterday was Friday
#7     7                     bung search engine
```

Comment: This is very cool. Thank you. By the way, would you happen to know how to add extra words into the hunspell dictionary in within R?

Comment: Glad it helped. For your question: I would have to look into that. This is a also quite different question than the original post, so I would post a new question for that.

Comment: by the way @Dan, is it possible to put ```FindReplace``` in parallel processing for faster processing?

Comment: that should be possible if you split `df1` into several chunks (since the operations done on one row in your data set are not affected by the information of the other rows)

Answer (score 2):

Let me leave another option for you although this case is solved by now. You tried using `str_replace_all()`. I used `stri_replace_all_fixed()` instead. The first step is to identify bad words and store them in `badwords`. The second step is to extract the first suggestion for each word using `hunspell_suggest()` in `sapply()` and store them in `suggestions`. Finally, I use these two vectors in `stri_replace_all_fixed()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(hunspell)

df1 <- data.frame("Index" = 1:7, "Text" = c("Brad came to dinner with us tonigh.",
                                            "Wuld you like to trave with me?",
                                            "There is so muh to undestand.",
                                            "Sentences cone in many shaes and sizes.",
                                            "Learnin R is fun",
                                            "yesterday was Friday",
                                            "bing search engine"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Get bad words.
badwords <- hunspell(df1$Text) %>% unlist

# Extract the first suggestion for each bad word.
suggestions <- sapply(hunspell_suggest(badwords), "[[", 1)

mutate(df1, Text = stri_replace_all_fixed(str = Text,
                                          pattern = badwords,
                                          replacement = suggestions,
                                          vectorize_all = FALSE)) -> out

#  Index                                   Text
#1     1   Brad came to dinner with us tonight.
#2     2        Wald you like to trace with me?
#3     3         There is so hum to understand.
#4     4 Sentences cone in many shes and sizes.
#5     5                      Learning R is fun
#6     6                   yesterday was Friday
#7     7                     bung search engine
```

Comment: this is great too. I tried it as well. Thank you @jazzurro

Comment: Also, can I use ```parallel``` with ```mutate``` since I have millions of rows that I need to replace after getting the suggestion? Thank you.