# Hunspell Workaround Empty Suggestion out of bounds error in R

Tags: r, list, hunspell

I am trying to automatically spell-check a string column of a data.table/data.frame.

Looking around, I found several approaches that all give an "out of bounds" error in the case `hunspell.suggest` returns no suggestions (that is, an empty list, e.g. "pippasnjfjsfiadjg"), see approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56031837/how-to-using-lapply-on-str-replace-all-and-hunspell-suggest-to-replace-all-missp?rq=1) (the accepted answer here yields NA so does work in principal) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026550/how-to-use-hunspell-package-to-suggest-correct-words-in-a-column-in-r)

We seem to require `unlist` in order to identify these empty suggestions and then exclude them from the part of the code that picks the first suggestion but I cannot figure out how.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(hunspell)

df1 <- data.frame("Index" = 1:7, "Text" = c("pippasnjfjsfiadjg came to dinner with us tonigh.",
                                            "Wuld you like to trave with me?",
                                            "There is so muh to undestand.",
                                            "Sentences cone in many shaes and sizes.",
                                            "Learnin R is fun",
                                            "yesterday was Friday",
                                            "bing search engine"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Get bad words.
badwords <- hunspell(df1$Text) %>% unlist

# Extract the first suggestion for each bad word.
suggestions <- sapply(hunspell_suggest(badwords), "[[", 1)

mutate(df1, Text = stri_replace_all_fixed(str = Text,
                                          pattern = badwords,
                                          replacement = suggestions,
                                          vectorize_all = FALSE)) -> out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to filter the list of bad words and suggestions to get rid of those without suggestions

```
badwords <- hunspell(df1$Text) %>% unlist()
# note use of '[' rather than '[['
suggestions <- sapply(hunspell_suggest(badwords), '[', 1)

badwords <- badwords[!is.na(suggestions)]
suggestions <- suggestions[!is.na(suggestions)]
```